# Why extra type variables are not allowed in class constraints?

Tags: haskell

Consider this little useless example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

f :: (b ~ [a], Show b) => a -> Int
f _ = 0
```

With `FlexibleContexts` extension it is possible to replace `f`'s context with equivalent but more readable one:

```
f :: Show [a] => a -> Int
```

Now consider the same setting only with class instead of function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

class Show [a] => F a
```

If I try to replace `F`'s context with equivalent but less readable one

```
class (b ~ [a], Show b) => F a
```

then I get `Not in scope: type variable ‘b’` from GHC.

Why it is not possible to use extra type variable in class context?
What is the reason for such a restriction?

Comment: interesting - what is the use case here if I may ask? After all (`Show a => Show [a]`) or is this just for demonstration? - Sadly I cannot really help with your question itself :(

Comment: Consider e.g. `instance (C a b, C b c) => C [a] [c]`. How would the compiler check whether `C [Int] [Char]` has an instance? Type `b` would be unknown when performing this search.

Comment: @CarstenKönig, I don't have any use case at hand, just noticed that asymmetry between contexts in classes and in function.

Comment: @chi, sorry, I don't see how your comment is related to the question.

Comment: @maxtaldykin I think I get what chi is trying to tell us - you could introduce really complicated relations

Comment: You asked "Why it is not possible to use extra type variable in class context?", but you focus on a very special case `b ~ [a]`. Maybe in such cases it would be easy to handle them. In the general case, however, things seem to be much more complex. My previous example uses a `b` only in the context to build a tricky instance. It's not meant to answer your question, but just a prod towards thinking about the full consequences of allowing extra variables on the context. If you want a class example, take `class (C a b, C b c) => C [a] [c]`: how would you instantiate it?

Comment: @chi, thank you for clarification, that makes sense. But if `b` is not class variable, it can't be used in class definition, so I don't bother how it will be instantiated. I only need to check if given `a` and `c` there are some instances `C a b` and `C b c` for some `b`.

Comment: @maxtaldykin What you are asking (write an instance of the form `C a b, C b c => C a c`) is impossible. The constraint solver is simply not powerful enough. You can probably do something like what you want if you refactor `C` to be a type family instead of a type class.

Comment: Right. Note that searching for "some `b`" can be quite complex. The correct type could be more complex than the known types `a` and `c`. For instance the solution could be `b = [[[...[Int]...]]]` where the number of nestings is large. My feeling is that type checking would become undecidable.

Comment: If my question is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270013/is-it-possible-to-introduce-additional-type-variables-into-a-superclass-constrai) one, then the answer is **"It is perfectly valid feature, just not yet implemented"**.